# Rolling standard deviation for every 5th day in R

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I have a time series dataframe which looks like

```
2014-02-05 2014-02-06 2014-02-07 2014-02-12 2014-02-14 2014-02-17 2014-02-18 2014-02-19 ......
    0.0379    -0.0008     0.0352     0.0379     0.0392     0.0173     0.0360     0.0371
```

I want to compute moving standard deviation for every 5th day data from this list in R. What I mean is that, I wish to select a sample in the form such that sample1[1] = 2014-02-05,  0.0379 , sample1[2] =2014-02-12, 0.0379.....and then find the std dev of this sample and then use a rolling standard deviation to move on to the next date i.e. sample2[1] =2014-02-06,  -0.0008 , sample2[2] =2014-02-12, 0.0379 and find the standard deviation of this list and so on. Since day available is irregular, I cannot use seq(1:l, by = ). In rollapply, the function would take every consecutive numbers to compute the standard deviation. Is there a way to sample every 5th day data from this list in an efficient way, or modify the standard deviation function somehow, to make it select every 5th day data and then compute the standard deviation on the available data. Any suggestion in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Very unclear this question it is... Can you provide some example desired output for that set above?

Comment: @ user3785531: your feedback on answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

**Restating Question** I am assuming you want to fill in missing days and then if z is the resulting series calculate the following

```
sd(c(z[1], z[6], z[11], z[16], z[21]))
sd(c(z[2], z[7], z[12], z[17], z[22]))
etc.
```

but only keeping those sd's which start at times found in `sample1`.

If that is not the intent of the question please clarify with further explanation and by giving an actual example of input and output.

**Answer** Create a daily grid `g` and merge with `sample1` filling in NAs from the end giving the filled in series `z`.  (Note that if points have gaps greater than 4 days then we do not fill those gaps since that would involve including points more than once in the sd.) Then use `rollapply` to compute the desired `sd` keeping only the original times.

```
g <- zoo(, seq(start(sample1), end(sample1), "day"))
z <- na.locf(merge(sample1, g), fromLast = TRUE, maxgap = 4)
r <- rollapply(z, 21, function(x) sd(x[seq(1, 21, 5)]), align = "left")
r[time(sample1)]
```

**Note** The `rollapply` statement could alternatively be written like this:

```
r <- rollapply(z, list(seq(0, length = 5, by = 5)), sd)
```

since the `width` argument can be specified as a list containing a vector of offsets.

**Update**  Revised again after re-reading question.  Also provided alternate `rollapply` expression.

Comment: Absolutely..that is exactly what I was looking at. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Following may be useful:

```
xx = structure(c(0.0379, -8e-04, 0.0352, 0.0379, 0.0392, 0.0173, 0.036, 
0.0371), .Names = c("2014-02-05", "2014-02-06", "2014-02-07", 
"2014-02-12", "2014-02-14", "2014-02-17", "2014-02-18", "2014-02-19"
))

xx
2014-02-05 2014-02-06 2014-02-07 2014-02-12 2014-02-14 2014-02-17 2014-02-18 2014-02-19 
    0.0379    -0.0008     0.0352     0.0379     0.0392     0.0173     0.0360     0.0371 
yy = as.numeric()
for(i in 5:length(xx)){
    yy[i]= sd(xx[(i-4):i])
}
yy
[1]          NA          NA          NA          NA 0.017212408 0.017278108 0.008982038 0.009130991
```

For a data frame version:

```
ddf = structure(list(date = structure(1:8, .Label = c("2014-02-05", 
"2014-02-06", "2014-02-07", "2014-02-12", "2014-02-14", "2014-02-17", 
"2014-02-18", "2014-02-19"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.0379, 
-8e-04, 0.0352, 0.0379, 0.0392, 0.0173, 0.036, 0.0371)), .Names = c("date", 
"value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))


ddf
        date   value
1 2014-02-05  0.0379
2 2014-02-06 -0.0008
3 2014-02-07  0.0352
4 2014-02-12  0.0379
5 2014-02-14  0.0392
6 2014-02-17  0.0173
7 2014-02-18  0.0360
8 2014-02-19  0.0371


ddf$rolling_sd=0
for(i in 5:nrow(ddf)){
    ddf$rolling_sd[i]= sd(ddf$value[(i-4):i])
}
ddf
        date   value  rolling_sd
1 2014-02-05  0.0379 0.000000000
2 2014-02-06 -0.0008 0.000000000
3 2014-02-07  0.0352 0.000000000
4 2014-02-12  0.0379 0.000000000
5 2014-02-14  0.0392 0.017212408
6 2014-02-17  0.0173 0.017278108
7 2014-02-18  0.0360 0.008982038
8 2014-02-19  0.0371 0.009130991
```